# Search for a word in webpage and save to TXT in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to: Load links from a .txt file, search for a specific Word, and if the word exists on that webpage, save the link to another .txt file but i am getting error: `No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant http://<_io.TextIOWrapper name='import.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1250'>?`
Note: the links has HTTPS://

The code:

```
import requests
list_of_pages = open('import.txt', 'r+')
save = open('output.txt', 'a+')
word = "Word"
save.truncate(0)
for page_link in list_of_pages:
    res = requests.get(list_of_pages)
    if word in res.text:
     response = requests.request("POST", url)
    save.write(str(response) + "\n")
```

Can anyone explain why ? thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Try putting http:// behind the links.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `res = requests.get(list_of_pages)` you're creating HTTP connection to `list_of_pages`. But `requests.get` takes URL string as a parameter (e.g. http://localhost:8080/static/image01.jpg), and look what `list_of_pages` is - it's an already opened file. Not a string. You have to either use *requests* library, or file IO API, not both.

If you have an already opened file, you don't need to create HTTP request at all. You don't need this `request.get()`. Parse `list_of_pages` like a normal, local file.

Or, if you would like to go the other way, don't open this text file in `list_of_arguments`, make it a string with URL of that file.